# Which module to use for path convinience functions in Angular/TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I use NodeJS and Angular/TS to create my Single Page Application (therefore browser/client side), and there I need to do modify some Url paths. I tried to use the `path` module, but this seems to only work on the server side (with express).

I also found the `url` module, but it doesn't have functions like `normalize`. One specific use case is to convert a path from A to B.

```
let A = "http://www.example.com/a/b/c"
let B = normalize(join(A, ".."));
console.log(B); // http://www.example.com/a/b/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/browserify/path-browserify

This module is part of the https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser collection, which is deprecated (idk why). However it is reputable and stable, so feel free to use it.